# How to make a batch of image patches, not separate patches

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I have written some lines of code to extract 5 bounding boxes/patches of a single image. When I run this code and print its output shape it's something like this `(5, 256)`, five patches each with a vector of 256. The problem is the separate extraction of patches from a single image, when I feed 5000+ images to this code, it generates `5000*5` patches mixed with each other. In this way, it loses the patch/image relationship. I want to change this code somehow to generate an output with batch information like this `(1, 5, 256)`. In this way, each batch will represent an image.

```
def create_vision_encoder(
num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate, trainable=False
):

  xception = keras.applications.Xception(
    include_top=False, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg"
)
  for layer in xception.layers:
    layer.trainable = trainable

  inputs = layers.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3), name="image_input")

  NUM_BOXES = 5
  CHANNELS = 3
  CROP_SIZE = (200, 200)

  boxes = tf.random.uniform(shape=(NUM_BOXES, 4))
  box_indices = tf.random.uniform(shape=(NUM_BOXES,), minval=0,
  maxval=BATCH_SIZE, dtype=tf.int32)
  output = tf.image.crop_and_resize(inputs, boxes, box_indices, CROP_SIZE)

  xception_input = tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input(output)
  embeddings = xception(xception_input)

  outputs = project_embeddings(
    embeddings, num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate
)

  return keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="vision_encoder")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `ImagePatchesAndEmbedding`  layer that will stack the captured bounding boxes and apply `xception`:

```
class ImagePatchesAndEmbedding(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, crop_size, num_boxes=5, minval=0, maxval=1):
        super(ImagePatchesAndEmbedding, self).__init__()
        self.crop_size = crop_size
        self.boxes = tf.random.uniform(shape=(num_boxes, 4))
        self.box_indices = tf.random.uniform(shape=(num_boxes,), minval=0,
                                             maxval=1, dtype=tf.int32)
        self.preprocess = tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        patches = tf.map_fn(lambda img:tf.image.crop_and_resize(img[None,...],
                        self.boxes, self.box_indices, self.crop_size), inputs)   
        embeddings = tf.map_fn(lambda patch: xception(self.preprocess(patch)), patches)
        return embeddings
```

Model,

```
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3), name="image_input")
NUM_BOXES = 5
CHANNELS = 3
CROP_SIZE = (200, 200)
BATCH_SIZE = 3
output = ImagePatchesAndEmbedding(CROP_SIZE, num_boxes=5, maxval=BATCH_SIZE)(inputs)
model = keras.Model(inputs, output)
```

Call model,

```
model(tf.random.normal(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, 299, 299, 3))).shape
#[3, 5, 2048]
```

Comment: Thanks @vijayachandran mariappan for your helpful answer, If you see I use a pre-train model `xception = keras.applications.Xception(
    include_top=False, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg"
)` with `inputs = layers.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3), name="image_input")`.
When I use crop size of `50*50` and extract 5 patches. It generates the following error `Input 0 of layer "batch_normalization" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 5, 13, 13, 96)`.

Comment: You need to apply tf.map_fn for xception also. Edited my answer to include this.

Comment: `tf.map_fn(lambda patch: xception` where you defined this exception. It says `NameError: name 'xception' is not defined` when I use this code.

Comment: xception = keras.applications.Xception(
    include_top=False, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg"
)